# Unexplained 'looser throw specifier' error from gcc c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code when compiled with gcc 5.4.0 displays a 'looser throw specifier error'. I don't see why.

```
class Err {
};

class A {
    public:
        A() {}
        ~A() throw(Err) {}
};

class Base {
    public:
        inline Base()  { }
        inline virtual ~Base() { }
};

class Derived : public virtual Base {
    public:
        A a;
        Derived() { }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

*g++ --std=c++11 -m64 -Wtype-limits -Wextra -ggdb -Wall -Werror  looserthrow.cpp   -o looserthrow

looserthrow.cpp:16:7: error: looser throw specifier for ‘virtual Derived::~Derived() throw (Err)’
 class Derived : public virtual Base {
       ^

looserthrow.cpp:13:24: error:   overriding ‘virtual Base::~Base() noexcept’
         inline virtual ~Base() { }
                        ^*

Please note the subtleties with this code which is different from previous topics. Here the Base class does not have throw specifier. So how could the Derived class have a looser throw specifier.

Comment: Throwing destructors are generally bad idea.

Comment: as are throw specifiers in general - useless, and now deprecated

Comment: Exception specifiers are deprecated. @pm100 they could've been very handy, but unfortunately they were removed instead of being properly enforced.

Comment: Maybe they'll "get it right" with `noexcept`

Comment: Not a very good choice choice of duplicate. The issue at the suggested "duplicate" link is loosely related, but based on a different version of rules. The key moment: the linked question demonstrates an error that existed since C++98, where the destructor of `std::exception` was explicitly declared as `throw()` aka `noexcept`. In this question `Base`' s destructor does not have an explicit exception specification. This problem depends critically on C++11's implicit behavior: `Base` destructor is `noexcept` by default. Note that C++98 would see the above code as valid.

Comment: Basically the answer to the OP's question is as follows: even though your `Base::~Base()` does not have an exception specification, according to the modern C++ rules your `Base::~Base()` is implicitly `noexcept`. Meanwhile, your `Derived::~Derived()` is a throwing destructor because of presence of `A a;` member. This is what leads to that  "looser throw specifier" error.

Comment: @AnT you are right. With c++11 implicit destructors are assumed noexcept.